# Perl 5.22 CLI 2.03

Tags: activeperl

I am facing problem for accessing my serial port device from Control::CLI( ver 2.03) on Perl 5.22. Issue is connection gets established but I can't write on the port.

The same code was working well with Control::CLI( ver 1.03) on Perl 5.14

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't more of information to go on but the problem sounds like it might be one of two areas:

1) there might be issues with the newer version of Control::CLI that you are using. This would be something to ask the maintainer of Control::CLI about.
Chances are you might need to modify your existing code.

2) the OS that you are running 5.22 on. What's not clear is if you ran 5.14 on an older version of Windows (ie, Win 7, Win XP) and are trying to run your script with 5.22 on a newer version (ie, Win 10).

Sorry that I can't give an exact answer but these would be areas I would advise looking into to begin troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using Windows 7 for both the versions of Perl.

Comment: Is both Win 7 and Perl 5.22 32-bit or 64-bit? And was 5.14 32-bit or 64-bit? If they are all the same bit, then it's probably something wrong with Control::CLI module itself and you should contact the maintainer at:

Comment: Sorry, the link I meant to put was: http://search.cpan.org/~lstevens/Control-CLI-2.01/lib/Control/CLI.pm      Please note that ActiveState does not maintain the Control::CLI module.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. Win 7 & Perl 5.22 are 64 bit. But I will check whether Perl 5.14 was 32 bit or 64 bit.

Comment: Well, I found out that Perl 5.14 version was 32 bit. Now I need 64 bit version of Perl 5.22. Also my some code part which runs perfectly on Perl 5.14 ( 32 bit) fails randomly on Perl 5.22 (64 bit). Could you please suggest which nmake.exe I should use for building modules manually?